# Using SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient lead to worse routes in OR-tools VRP

Tags: optimization, routes, or-tools

I'm using OR-tools VRP to create delivery routes. I have distance as a dimension, a dimension to constrain the number of delivery points per route and my code is very similar to the guide shared in https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrp

The issue I have is that when using SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient as below, the resulting routes have very short distances from the depot to the first delivery point and from the last delivery point to the depot, but instead, the distances between delivery points is high. Instead, when not using this SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient the routes have very low distances between delivery points but the distance from and to the depot are higher.

```
distance_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(dimension_name)
distance_dimension.SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(100)
```

Also, when not using the span cost, the sum of the distances of all routes is lower. Based on the metrics and how the routes look in a map, I think that not using the span cost is better. See the routes on the images below, first not using the span cost and second using it.

[image: Not using span cost]
[image: Using span cost]

My concern is that if I'm not using the span cost, I don't know if the solver is optimizing the routes or it just creates a greedy solution (I'm using PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC as first solution strategy). Can someone explain why I'm getting these routes in both cases and tell me if the routes I'm getting when not using the span are optimal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases you'll always have the arc cost added to the objective, the global span cost coefficient add an EXTRA cost being `coeff * (max_end - min_start)`
note: When using a coefficient of 100 it just makes this cost the dominant factor...

First the solver try to create an initial solution using the first strategy heuristic.

Then if local search is enable, solution may be improved drastically
-> do you enable local search ?

```py
    search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = (
        routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH)
    search_parameters.log_search = True
    search_parameters.time_limit.FromSeconds(20)
```

Comment: Since I'm only using a distance dimension, the max_end and min_start are referring to the maximum distance of any route and the minimum distance of any route? 

Regarding the search parameters I'm using 
`search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)`

I don't really know which are the default parameters but I've tried using the GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH during 10 min and the results are almost identical.

Comment: Mizux, could you confirm whether the max_end and min_start are the maximum and minimum distances of all routes? If not, could you give any additional detail on what they are? Thanks!

Comment: yes since it is a "Global Span", otherwise it is "Span" and take a vehicle index.
see: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/fa84bc05e72641dddfbb98164d81b8bc9bef6ea5/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L2482-L2488